# How to add collapsible icon for tab which is showing grid in the admin panel using ui component?

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.3, admin, grid-layout, collapsible

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">
                pmr_article_hierarchy_grid.pmr_article_hierarchy_grid_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">
                pmr_article_hierarchy_grid.pmr_article_hierarchy_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">pmr_article_hierarchy_grid_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="pmr_article_hierarchy_grid_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">
                Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">pmr_article_hierarchy_grid_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render" />
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                 <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext" />
        <bookmark name="bookmarks" />
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls" />
        <filters name="listing_filters" />
        <!-- Paging -->
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">
                            catalogreport_manage_listing.catalogreport_manage_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">
                        catalogreport_manage_listing.catalogreport_manage_listing.catalogreport_manage_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
        <exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToCsv</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToXml</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
    </container>
    <columns name="pmr_article_hierarchy_grid_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="pmr_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Pmr Id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="pmr_rule_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Pmr Rule Id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="article_code">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Article Code</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="is_exclude_flag">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is Exclude Flag</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```